# Counting the number of unique permutations

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> Suppose a string consists of `N` `0`'s and `M` `1`'s. How many unique
>   permutations of this string start with `1`?

I have the answer. It's apparently:

> $M+N-1 \choose N$

The explanation is to fix a `1` at the first position, which leaves `M-1` `1`'s and `N` `0`'s. Then the number of remaining unique permutations is simply `M+N-1` choose `N`. Can someone please help me understand why this is? I don't understand why we're only selecting `N` of the pieces left.

Comment: You are selecting the $N$ zeros. Once you have selected them, there's nothing else to do --- the $M-1$ ones fall into place.

Comment: You have had some answers. Are you happy with them? Is there something you still don't get?

Comment: Are you still here, Staksy?

Answer (score 1):

Each string of length $N + M$ consists of $N$ zeros and $M$ ones.  If the first number in the string is a $1$, we must fill the remaining $N + M - 1$ spaces with $N$ zeros and $M - 1$ ones.  Once we choose which of the $N + M - 1$ spaces to fill with $N$ zeros, there is only one way to fill the remaining $M - 1$ spaces with a $1$ (fill all of them with a $1$).  Thus, the number of ways we can construct a string of length $N + M$ that begins with a $1$ consisting of $N$ zeros and $M$ ones is $$\binom{M + N - 1}{N}\binom{M - 1}{M -1} = \binom{M + N - 1}{N} \cdot 1 = \binom{M + N - 1}{N}$$

Answer (score 0):

Once we put a $1$ at the first position, we next need to build a sequence of length $M+N-1$. Now each unique sequence can be described by which of its $N$ locations contain a zero. Right? If I tell you the positions of all the zeroes, then you also know the positions of all the ones.
OK, so of the $M-N-1$ positions in our sequence, let us select $N$ of them to contain a zero. How many ways can we do that? ${M+N-1 \choose N}$.

You might have noticed we can also specify a sequence by saying where the $M-1$ remaining ones go. What answer does that give you and why is it the same answer?